# Redirection doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html

I have test.html page, when it is loaded, I am redirecting it to another page:

```
window.location.href = 'https://some.page'
```

But then when I am trying to get html source of new page:

```
console.log("innerHTML " + window.document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

I am still getting html source of old test.html page. How can I access to new loaded page http://some.page?

Comment: Can you provide full code?

Comment: Setting window.location is an async task. are you waiting for it to complete?

Comment: Try document.location.href='url' or window.open('url')

Comment: I try to understand , when you open your add-in you want to open another page and then get the innerHTML in the js of the previous page ? it's sounds wired , it's not possible if this is what you want to get ..

Comment: Run the console.log command from the new page, not the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){ 
    window.open("https://some.page")
});
```

This function first loads the document and then executes what is inside.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
 console.log("innerHTML : " + window.document.documentElement.innerHTML); 
}

window.location.href = 'https://some.page';
```

Comment: The same result. Maybe issue is related that it is plug-in